# Postgresql write csv to table loop failing unexpectedly mid-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to iterate through a series of CSV files (all of which have identical table structure), with a for loop reading each CSV file in, writing it to a postgresql table (same structure as CSV files), and iterating on to the next CSV file.

I've got about 600 CSVs I want to iterate through, and my for loop works flawlessly for the first 33 iterations, but for some reason every single iteration after that fails.

At first I thought it was an issue with the constraints I'd placed on the fields within my postgrgesql table (i.e. NOT NULL/UNIQUE constraints). However when I attempt to write any of the files manually via Postico they commit without any issue (which also weeds out any data type mis-matches as a potential cause I think?).

```py
import psycopg2
from lister import list_generator

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=backend user=macbookpro")
cur = conn.cursor()

list = list_generator('testing.csv')

n = 0

for a in list:
    try:
        with open('Testing/'+ str(a) +'.csv', 'rb') as f:
            next(f)
            cur.copy_from(f, 'table1', sep=',')
            conn.commit()
            print(str(n) + " " + str(a) + " completed")
            n += 1
    except:
        print(str(n) + " " + str(a) + " failed")
        n += 1
        pass
```

Comment: What error message do you get when they fail?

Comment: Since I have it nested in a try/except block, the message I get is the print statement designated in the except block. Let me drop the try/except block and I'll update. Thanks Nick.

Comment: Looks like its a datatype error after all. Throwing the following error: psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "". Strange the datatype error doesn't occur on manual import though, no?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a null value treatment issue. CSVs written from pandas dataframes write NaN as "". Passing null="" as an argument in the copy_from statement and changing a few datatypes from int to float resolved the issue.